# Brother printe Laser faded text

Tags: windows-10, brother-printer

Brother printer, Laser MFC-L2740, prints a faded text.
I changed the toner, changed the drum, still the same problem. I cleaned my head, still the same problem.
He also takes out a faded page in the "test".

Comment: Brother usually provides a troubleshooting guide for laser printer quality problems. The things listed in there are usually all you can do outside having the printer serviced. Somebody should see the problem to make any type of guess.

Comment: Im not qualitied to comment, but could the fuser unit need replacing? The fuser unit is, as I understand it, responsible for fusong the toner to the page.

Answer (score 1):

This is the Brother print quality troubleshooting guide for your printer: https://support.brother.com/g/s/id/htmldoc/mfc/cv_dcpl2520dw/use/manual/index.html#GUID-EEC1EE16-C8ED-4BC3-B3C4-27B0AACF0D44_516

Follow the suggestions under the “faint” print topic. Light print is not a typical print problem requiring repair. Light print is usually a problem with your printer supplies, making it a consumables problem and not a printer hardware problem. Use a **genuine** brother toner cartridge and drum unit. Also check for the “toner save” feature that might be turned on.

If the light print continues, it is almost certainly the transfer roller that is causing the issue. However, it can be an electrical issue as well as an issue with the laser assembly.

Transfer rollers are usually a simple replacement but I don’t see a transfer roller available for this model of printer. Therefore, if using new, genuine supplies does not fix the problem the printer is not serviceable or is not worth the cost of repairing.

Comment: Find where the problem is.
The plastic pin that enters the toner on the left side of the printer, and rotates it, breaks.
Now I'm in trouble getting a pin.